# Is this the proper way to use the word ‘aspirant’?

Tags: word-usage

I am new to the workforce and thought it would be a good idea to create a profile to attract new job opportunities. One of the requirements, when setting up the account, is having an appealing header.

I have come up with the header provided below, and would like to know if I am using the word ‘aspirant’ in the proper context. If not, could someone please recommend another word I could use in place of it. Thank you so much for your time.

> ITIL and ServiceNow Administrator certified **aspirant** eager for new
>   opportunities.

Comment: Which certification authority certifies aspirants and what are the qualifications?

Comment: I would keep it all presently factual and professional, not futurely potential and personal. 'Certified ITIL and ServiceNow Administrator seeks new opportunities.'

Answer (score 1):

If by *aspirant* (which sounds much like *perspirant*), you mean that you aspire to be certified but are not (certified), the contradiction from the lead-in risks putting off a number of sourcers/recruiters who found your resume because it returned a hit (false positive, in this case) on those search terms

It is an unconventional phrase (perhaps for the reasons outlined above) and [the word "aspirant" itself is in the bottom 40% in terms of usage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aspirant), so it is on the edges of understandable vocabulary, and lends itself to be misinterpreted as the case above. *eager* sufficiently expresses gumption in this case; suggest replacing with **professional** (eg: *ITIL certified professional eager...*)

Comment: Carly, thank you very much, for your input. After reviewing what you had written, I can see how a misunderstanding could occur. I shall take your advice into consideration. Your help is very much appreciated. I hope you have a great day.